# Makefile in C to get an executable

Tags: c, makefile

How can I get a makefile of my C program  that will build/compile my program and generates an 
executable.This executive should be able to run my c program???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called `Makefile` on the same path with this content:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
OBJECTS = filename.o

all: appname

filename.o: filename.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c filename.c

appname: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o appname
```

Note: There must be a "tab" (not spaces) before

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c filename.c
```

and

```
$(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o appname
```

Then run:

```
make
```

---

**EDIT:** An example:

```
david@debian:~$ cat demo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    return 0;
}

david@debian:~$ cat Makefile
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
OBJECTS = demo.o

all: demo

demo.o: demo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c demo.c

demo: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o demo

david@debian:~$ make
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -c demo.c
gcc demo.o -o demo
```

Comment: I am getting this error-
    `No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`
I have made sure I used tab and also I have saved my makefile in the same directory as my code

Comment: Create a file called `Makefile`, replace `filename` with the name of your C file

Comment: Yes I did that earlier,but as I said I got that error.

Comment: This is what I am doing

    `CC = gcc
     CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
     OBJECTS = abc.o

     all: exe

     abc.o: abc.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c abc.c

     exe: $(OBJECTS)
 `$(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o exe `

Comment: I am doing the same,but I am using MinGW gcc compiler.I am typing this command at the beginning- `mingw32-make` .This gives me the error as I mentioned above

Comment: Take a look: [Minimalist GNU for Windows - Make](http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/Makefile)

Comment: I am following exactly the same steps,but still I am getting the error.Thanks a lot anyway.I think there is some problem with MinGW gcc,which compiler are you using???

Comment: gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2

Comment: Also can you tell me the should be a .txt extension or what?From what i have read it doesnt depend on the extension.Also is M small or capital in Makefile???

Comment: You don't need an extension like .txt, and you can use both `Makefile` or `makefile` as filename.

Answer (score 2):

Save the makefile as `makefile` or `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all
all : progname
progname: all-objects
```

1. `.PHONY` to mark the target `all` as not a file-target
2. `all` is the first and thus default-target, depends on `progname` (Just so `make all` works)
3. `progname` depends on all the object-files, and will thus link them together.
4. The object-files are built using builtin rules.

If you want to override the default-action of a rule, write your own recipe.
Each command-line must be indented one tab (do not use spaces).

Reference of GNU make: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html
Reference of builtin rules: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: Could be simpler -- just one line `prognam: objects...`

Comment: Sure, but one just assumes `make all` to do something sensible.